Class to change a customtkinter button's image is not working
To give some context, I am writing the code to a button which starts off as a 'password hidden' image, which looks like a closed eye. Once you press it, it should change the image to a 'password shown' image, which looks like an open eye.
Here's the class I wrote to change the image:
from PIL import Image
import customtkinter as ctk

class ShowHidePasswordImages:
    def __init__(self, target):
        # Image which is shown when the password is hidden
        password_hidden_image_path = "PasswordHiddenImage.png"
        password_hidden_image = Image.open(password_hidden_image_path)
        password_hidden_image = password_hidden_image.resize((20, 20))  # Resize to fit button
        self.password_hidden_image = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=password_hidden_image, size=(20, 20))

        # Image which is shown when the password is shown
        password_shown_image_path = "PasswordShownImage.png"
        password_shown_image = Image.open(password_shown_image_path)
        password_shown_image = password_shown_image.resize((20, 20))  # Resize to fit button
        self.password_shown_image = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=password_shown_image, size=(20, 20))
        if target.cget('image') is None:
            target.configure(image=self.password_hidden_image)
        target.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: check_current_image())

        def check_current_image():
            if target.cget('image') == self.password_hidden_image:
                target.configure(image=self.password_shown_image)
            elif target.cget('image') == self.password_shown_image:
                target.configure(image=self.password_hidden_image)
            return

And here's the button I am referencing:
self.show_hide_password = ctk.CTkButton(self.details_frame, width=10, height=10,
                       corner_radius=20,text="",command=self.show_hide_password)
MyCustomFunctions.ShowHidePasswordImages(self.show_hide_password)

I have a couple of problems here:
Why doesn't the button automatically have the password hidden image, as the image is None and as seen in the class, if the image is None the image should become the self.password_hidden_image.
Also, when I click the button, nothing happens even though it should change the button's image.
